# Overwriting shapefile or feature class using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I can copy a shapefile but I want to be able to overwrite the copied shapefile to prevent multiple copies being created each time I run the program. I would also like for the saving and renaming of the copied shapefile to happen behind the scenes i.e. the user doesnt see a gxDialog box.

How do I overwrite the copied file, either as a shapefile or feature class?

Comment: a good test of any method would be to see how it handles the presence of a .shx file (or .prj or .dbf) when there is no .shp there.  I haven't looked lately, but found the most reliable way is to just do a filesystem delete of shpfile.*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before making the copy of the feature class, you can open the containing workspace and check the existance of the feature class ([IWorkspace2.NameExists](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/IWorkspace2_NameExists.htm)), and if exists then delete it ([IDataset.Delete](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/componenthelp/esrigeodatabase/IDataset_Delete.htm)).

Example:

```
Dim pWorkspace2 as IWorkspace2
set pWorkspace2 = yourWorkspace

' Checks the existance of the feature class
If pWorkspace2.NameExists(yourDestFeatureClass) Then

   Dim pFeatureWorkspace as IFeatureWorkspace
   set pFeatureWorkspace = yourWorkspace

   ' Open the feature class and cast it to the IDataset interface
   Dim pDataset as IDataset
   set pDataset = pFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(yourDestFeatureClass)

   ' Removes the feature class
   pDataset.Delete

End if

' Your code to make the copy...
```

Comment: Thanks! That code works great for deleting the feature class. However I am having trouble copying a feature class, it seems that the IDataset.Copy won't work for copying a feature dataset, is there easy code to get around this?

Comment: Try with IGeoDBDataTransfer. Here is an example:http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esrigeodatabase/Copy_Paste.htm

Comment: It doesn't work with ArcObjects for Java... If you cast a IFeatureClass to a IDataset like that: IDataset dataset = (IDataset)featureWorkspace.openFeatureClass(fc); then you get a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 1):

This code was much easier to use to copy a file geodatabase feature class. Can't find the source but it was obtained through a google search.

```
Sub CopyFC(pOldWorkspace As IWorkspace, FCname As String, copyWorkSpace As IWorkspace)
    Dim gp As Object
    Set gp = CreateObject("esriGeoprocessing.GPDispatch")
    Dim pEnumDataset As IEnumDataset
    Dim pDataset As IDataset
    Dim pFeatClass As IFeatureClass
    Dim pEnumFeatClass As IEnumFeatureClass
    Set pEnumDataset = pOldWorkspace.Datasets(esriDTFeatureClass)
    Set pDataset = pEnumDataset.Next
    While Not pDataset Is Nothing
    If pDataset.BrowseName = FCname Then
        'get FC from pdataset
        Dim inFC As IFeatureClass
        Set inFC = pDataset

        gp.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion inFC, copyWorkSpace, pDataset.BrowseName
    End If
    Set pDataset = pEnumDataset.Next
 Wend
End Sub
```