# How to delete a feature class from a GDB using ArcObjects for Java?

Tags: arcobjects, java, file-geodatabase, feature-class

I've seen this solution which may works in ArcObjects for VB/.Net:

[How to overwrite a shapefile or feature class using arcobjects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25397/how-to-overwrite-a-shapefile-or-feature-class-using-arcobjects)

When I try to convert it into Java, I get a `ClassCastException` on the `IDataset` cast.

Here is my code:

```
IWorkspace workspace = ...
IWorkspace2 workspace2 = (IWorkspace2)workspace;
if(workspace2.isNameExists(esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureClass, featureClassName)) {
    IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspace;
     // ClassCastException here
    IDataset featureClassDataset = (IDataset)featureWorkspace.openFeatureClass(featureClassName);
    if(featureClassDataset.canDelete()) {
        featureClassDataset.delete();
    } else {
        // alert: the feature class exists but couldn't be deleted
    }
}
IFeatureClass featureClass = featureDataset.createFeatureClass(...);
```

Does anyone know how we can't use the `IDataset` interface for a feature class as in VB?

How to delete a feature class in Java else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: the problem came from the way I created the IWorkspace object.
The best way to do it in ArcObjects API for Java is:

```
    IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactory();
    IWorkspaceName workspaceName = workspaceFactory.create(parentDirectory, gdbName, null, 0);
    IName name = (IName)workspaceName;
    IWorkspace workspace = new Workspace(name.open());
```

even if in the [ESRI documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#/How_to_create_new_geodatabases/0001000002w4000000/), it's written to use `new IWorkspaceProxy(name.open())` (I think that's en error).